# Java requestFocus() not working at the constructor

Tags: java, focus, request

In my Java Swing Application Reuestfocus method not working at the Constructor. But it works if I used requestfocus along with button action listener. I want set Requestfocus at the form load. I dont understand whats the wrong here. P.S I use JInternal Frame

```
  txtItemName.requestFocusInWindow (); // did not work
  txtItemName.requestFocus ();  // did not work
```

---

```
  public ItemMgt() {

        initComponents();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                    txtItemName.requestFocus(); // did not work
              }
        });
  }
```

---

```
  private void formInternalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        txtItemName.requestFocus(); // did not work.
  }
```

Comment: Are you using it in JFrame?

Comment: @Sudhanshu Sorry I forgot to mention. I use Internal Frame

Comment: What do you expect to happen when four components request focus on object creation before it is visible? Which one should get it?

Answer (score 2):

The case might by that your component is not visible, so the GUI manager can not set focus on it.

As is specified in documentation:

> (..) component must be displayable, focusable, **visible** and all of its ancestors (with the exception of the top-level Window) must be visible for the request to be granted.

Generally you should avoid to have so robust logic in constructor. Your graphic components should be constructed first. When this is finished they should be adjusted to your preferences.

Instead of [requestFocus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus%28%29), it is recomended to use [requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) for more please visit the tutorial: [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Comment: thnx for your reply. But do you have any idea how can i fix that?

Comment: Yes, through reading the tutorial. I can not write you a quick fix as i do not know how you mange your GUI in general. After the reading, you for sure will be able to manage the problem by your self. Good luck!

Comment: I tried few available option. But nothing worked for me so far. Im still struggling to get the requestfocus to text field on Internal Frame. I tried using requestFocusInWindow() as well as SwingUtilities,Invokelater method on constructor as well. Is there any chance u can give me hand to fix this. Please. I updated the Original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netbeans IDE, then its much easier. Just make sure that all controls before your textbox are not focusable by unchecking the 'focusable' property in the Properties window. This will leave your textbox as the first focusable control thus allowing it to receive focus when the internal frame is opened

Comment: What if you do want to use TAB to travel to another control, though?

Comment: @Florin All other controls will receive focus when you press tab key if their 'focusable' property remains checked